# Separating a string using Spaces

Tags: vb.net

I am having a value "90672.40    91796473.18" in one variable.
I need to store the "90672.40" in an another variable and remaining in another variable. 
and also I need to retrieve a numbers from the 40th position to end.
kindly help me..

for your information,
I am having a variable named `lsline`.

Value of lsline is:

```
lsline = 15-OCT-08 OTHERS                               90672.40    91796473.18
```

i need to retrieve a number from 40th position, but i dont want the numbers after the space, i just want "90672.40" to store in a another variable.

Comment: did u get your answer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just split into an array

```
Dim values = Isline.Split(" ")
Dim number = CDec(value[2])
```

Comment: Very Thank you Matt Tew.. Can you explain how to separate that numeric value by their position.. instead of using array concept.

Comment: This won’t even compile with `Option Strict On` and, as such, is bad code.

Comment: Even with `Option Strict Off`, this code won't compile (wrong variable name, use of brackets not supported in VB).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Substring` to get part of a string if you don't want to use `Split`. The following returns 8 characters starting from number 40:

```
lsline.Substring(40, 8)
```